# module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'. Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    # make 'daemon' attribute always return False
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, val):
        pass


class NoDaemonProcessPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

    def Process(self, *args, **kwds):
        proc = super(NoDaemonProcessPool, self).Process(*args, **kwds)
        proc.__class__ = NoDaemonProcess

        return proc
```

In class NoDaemonProcessPool, there raise a error which looks like python can not find multiprocessing.pool

```
    class NoDaemonProcessPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'. Did you mean: 'Pool'?
```

I do not have any idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `pool` submodule of the `multiprocessing` package is not imported eagerly by default. Instead, it is loaded the first time `multiprocessing.Pool` is called. If you want to inherit from `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, you need to explicitly import the submodule yourself or it might not work.

Try:

```
import multiprocessing.pool # add the submodule here!

class NoDaemonProcessPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
   ...
```